# I get an error in my React app on clicking on links and by default when running it... can anyone help? What could be the problem?

Tags: reactjs, onclicklistener, uncaught-reference-error

This error is displayed when running the react app using npm start:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scugU.png)

Also whenever something is clicked, this error is displayed instead of performing the function. There is no "dd" named variable used or defined

> dd is not defined
>
> ReferenceError: dd is not defined
> at IL (:1:188)
> at :1:1713